# Removing Repeating Ad Banner After First Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add an ad banner in the main content area of my homepage underneath the first post only, but when I add the tag code it is putting it under each post within the main content. I only want the ad to appear under the first post. Can someone please help?

www.blackcelebkids.com

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You added it to the post template, so you must conditionalize it or move it elsewhere.

Comment: You need to show us some code! How should we guess how you insert that ads?

Comment: Probably you put your ad banner's code into loop. So for each content you see an ad banner. Can you post your code's looping part here?

Comment: hello ritcher please manage your code loop in bellow define post loop. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
               <?php $i=1; ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php 
                        //your post code here
                    ?>
                    <?php 
                        if($i==1){
                            /*put your banner code here*/
                        }
                     ?>
                <?php 
                    $i++;
                    endwhile; 
                ?>
```